# Why str.FirstChar() does not return the first char?

Tags: c++builder

```
 UnicodeString us = "12345";
 Label1->Caption= us.FirstChar();
```

The caption will show "12345" instead of "1".
Why is that?

The help page for FirstChar is empty:

> Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional
>   information. Please help us document this topic by using the
>   Discussion page!

The declaration is this:

```
const WideChar*    FirstChar() const;
const WideChar*    LastChar() const;
WideChar*          FirstChar();
WideChar*          LastChar();
```

Comment: Nope. It won't compile if I pass a parameter.

Comment: What is the type of caption? You should assign the result to a `wchar_t` variable.

Comment: Caption is the caption of a form or of a TLabel

Comment: It obviously returns a **pointer** to the first char. And it should be assigned to a `wchar_t*` variable. There is also a `LastChar()`, and guess what it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`UnicodeString::FirstChar()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.FirstChar) method returns a *pointer* to the first character (just as the [`UnicodeString::LastChar()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.LastChar) returns a *pointer* to the last character).

The data being pointed to is null-terminated.  So the statement `Label1->Caption = us.FirstChar();` is the same as if you had written `Label1->Caption = L"12345";` instead.  The `TLabel::Caption` property is also a `UnicodeString`, which has a constructor that accepts a null-terminated `WideChar*` pointer as input.  That is why you see the result you are getting.

If you want just the first character by itself, use [`UnicodeString::operator[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.operator_H5BH5D) instead:

```
Label1->Caption = us[1]; // UnicodeString is 1-indexed!
```

Or, using `FirstChar()`, simply dereference the pointer:

```
Label1->Caption = *(us.FirstChar());
```

Note that if the [`UnicodeString::IsEmpty()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UnicodeString.IsEmpty) method returns true, both approaches will fail.  `operator[]` will throw an [`ERangeError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.ERangeError) exception.  `FirstChar()` will return a `NULL` pointer, which is *undefined behavior* to dereference. So watch out for that, eg:

```
if (!us.IsEmpty())
    Label1->Caption = us[1];
else
    Label1->Caption = _D("");
```

```
if (!us.IsEmpty())
    Label1->Caption = *(us.FirstChar());
else
    Label1->Caption = _D("");
```

A safer option would be to use the [`UnicodeString::SubString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.SubString)  method instead, which will return an empty string if the requested substring is out of range:

```
Label1->Caption = us.SubString(1, 1); // also 1-indexed!
```

Alternatively, you can use the RTL's [`System::Strutils::LeftStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.StrUtils.LeftStr) function instead:

```
#include <System.StrUtils.hpp>

Label1->Caption = LeftStr(us, 1);
```